# C++ checking uninitialized iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, initialization, segmentation-fault

I waste a huge amount of time because I forget to initialize iterators then try to access the data they're supposed to be pointing to. The only marker that you get for making this kind of error is a segmentation fault at run time. Here's an example:

```
vector<Foo> V;
//Uninitialized pointer:
vector<Foo>::iterator it;
//....loads of code later, attempt to access pointer that points to nothing
(*it);
//Segmentation fault!
```

Is there a standard technique to do this sort of checking automatically at compile time?

Comment: Pragmatic solution: Move the iterator definition past the *"... loads of code"* bit.

Comment: Use idiomatic code? `for (auto it = v.begin(); ...)`

Comment: How about reducing the “loads of code” to “a tiny bit of code?”

Comment: Declare the iterator as late as possible, and initialise it on declaration.

Comment: I would love to, but the iterator is contained in a wrapper. I'm trying to abstract the implementation `vector<Foo>` away from a generic algorithm, so I control the iterator with member functions of the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

At compile time? No.

I can think of a couple of run-time helpers. First is to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/optional/doc/optional.html). The second is to set up a sentinel vector that you can use to initialize the iterator.

```
static vector<Foo> null_vector;
vector<Foo>::iterator it = null_vector.begin();
...
if (it == null_vector.begin())
```

Comment: Sentinels are a gross code smell, but this one is better.  Come to think of it, that's all `optional` is anyway in many cases.  I can't say I disagree with your answer, and in fact I do agree with `optional`, so +1.

Comment: @JohnDibling, some people have an aversion to `boost` for some reason so I provided an alternative.

Comment: Sure, makes sense.  I can't use Boost for production code yet, either.  To that end, I developed my own `optional`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++14, it's acceptable to [compare value initialized iterators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf). (Adopted 2013-04)

So this is true:

```
vector<int>::iterator i1{};
vector<int>::iterator i2{};
assert(i1 == i2);
```

but this is still invalid:

```
vector<int>::iterator i1;
vector<int>::iterator i2;
assert(i1 == i2);
```

I'm not sure which compilers support this yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few techniques I use in real code.  None are exactly what you're looking for.

First, as a programming practice, I generally instantiate a variable close to where it is needed, and at a time when I can initialize it.  I never instantiate an uninitialized variable.

Sometimes it is impossible to instantiate and initialize in one spot.  In these cases, I'll use something like Boost's `optional`, and at the point where I need to use it I'll check to see if the `optional` has been set.

Often I have found that when it's impossible to instantiate and initialize in one spot, it's because the design of some function is clumsy and unwieldly, or it is trying to do too much.  Try to break these responsibilities up in to multiple functions, and you might find the initial problem -- not being able to initialize & instantiate in one spot -- goes away and much cleaner code is yielded.